# Background color not being applied in java application

Tags: java, colors, background

My background color is not being applied for my Java application. I've tried looking through some of the answers and they all suggest using getContentPane() which is what I have been using.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class higherLower extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static int WIDTH = 300;
    public static int HEIGHT = WIDTH / 2;
    public static final String TITLE = "Higher/Lower";
    JTextField input = new JTextField();

    public higherLower(){
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //this.add(input);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new higherLower();
    }
}
```

So I'm not entirely sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Try `setOpaque(true)` - not sure if it helps

Comment: setOpaque() does not exist. setOpacity does and when I try using that it throws out a "Exception in thread blah blah: The Frame is decorated at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(unknownSource)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `paint` method which is short circuiting the paint functionality of the frame

Comment: You're faster than me!

Answer (score 1):

Why have you overridden paint(Graphics) for doing nothing?

Just remove your override and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks *facepalm* I'm still a java noob